# How to change text "Unlike" in blog detail Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

When i click "Like" in blog detail, it will change to "Unlike". Now i want to change text "Unlike" to "Like" with style bold ("**Like**"). How to change this text, help me. Thank you very much

[image: Unlike blog detial]

Answer (score 0):

It is expected result. After you click "Like", it will be changed to "Unlike" as you just could like a blog one time.

If you want to show it as "Like" like before, you can click "Unlike", it will be changed to "Like".

Comment: I know but i want to change text "Unlike" => "Like" with style bold

Comment: By default, we can just Like one time. If you just change the Text to "Like", the function of the button still is for "Unlike". If you want the customer to like multiple times, I suggest you create a custom button to count the times as "Like". Anyway, if you just want to change the text with bold, you can use JavaScript code to do that.